# No effect on PHP/SQL Delete on table

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

Basically my delete button is not functioning as intended. below is the screenshot of my for each table, displaying the contents of my table "product". I echoed the "productid" to show that the delete button has an int value.

[image: output]

**products.php**

```
 <td>
   <?php echo $rowProduct['productid']; ?>
     <a href="clinics_buttons.vc.php<?php echo '?delete-coupon='.$rowProduct['productid']; ?>" onclick="return confirm('Delete this address?');">
       <button class="btn btn-danger btn-sm full_width" data-toggle="modal">
          <i class="fa fa-edit"></i><?php echo "DELETE"; ?>
       </button>
     </a>
 </td>
```

I made the "delete-coupon" into a variable for use in the SQL. But even when '$productid' has a value, the table does not get deleted. Would like help on why this is happening and what could I add to fix it.

**clinics_buttons.vc.php**

```
<?php
session_start();

$routePath = "../";
require_once($routePath . "_config/db.php");
  $dbConfig = new config_db();
  $db = $dbConfig->init();

$delete_coupon = $_GET['delete-coupon'];

if (isset($_GET['delete-coupon'])) {
  $stmt = $db->prepare("DELETE FROM `product` WHERE productid = $delete_coupon");
  $stmt->execute();
  header('Location: ' . $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']);
  }
?>
```

Table Products

[image: table]

Comment: change `$delete_coupon` with `{$delete_coupon}` or `var_dump` your last executed query

Comment: `<button>` inside `<a href`? Remove that button and add `class="btn btn-danger btn-sm full_width"` to your `<a href` to make it look like a button

Comment: Note: although you are using a prepared statement, this code is subject to SQL injection and this not safe.

Comment: ....("DELETE FROM product WHERE productid = '$delete_coupon'");

Comment: Is the table called `product` or `Products`?

Comment: Seems like TYPO mistake.`DELETE FROM product` needs to be `DELETE FROM products`. as well as change delete button code like this:- `<a class="btn btn-danger btn-sm full_width" href="clinics_buttons.vc.php<?php echo '?delete-coupon='.$rowProduct['productid']; ?>" onclick="return confirm('Delete this address?');"><i class="fa fa-edit"></i><?php echo "DELETE"; ?></a>`

Comment: my table is called product

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably have "form" tag surrounding that table so "button" will trigger form submission.

Comment: this did the trick, did not realise the form tag was causing the issue, thanks